# Parent css transform affecting d3.mouse points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, mouseevent, transform

I'm using a third library that is adding 'transform: translate3d(200,0,0);' to a parent element. So the elements within the svg tend to move to the right. For drag&drop events, setting the origin is enough, but I'm having troubles to get corrected the d3.mouse(this).

I have created a jsfiddle of this example: http://bl.ocks.org/hlucasfranca/f133da4493553963e710

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/5jp6123u/

So, when clicking without applying the transform to the parent, everything is ok, but when the parent has the transform, d3.mouse returns a wrong number

```
var coords = d3.mouse(this);
coords[0] === 100; //true without transform..
coords[0] === 300; // true when the transform to the parent is applied.
// the values are not precise but you can verify the behavior in the jsfiddle
```

1. Why d3.mouse(this) is not able to get the correct value ?

my understanding is that d3.mouse should get the coords based on the container this ( svg ).

2. What should I do to fix the behavior keeping the parent with the new transform?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Not working in Firefox 46 for ubuntu

Working well in chrome and opera

Comment: I'm using Opera and everything looks right. No errors. Maybe it's your browser?

Comment: Interesting, let me try and I will update the question.

Comment: Just to add more info: This works correctly for me in Chrome (v50.0) but breaks, as you describe, in Firefox (v46.0).

Comment: @Klaujesi yes, you right, definitely I'm having troubles in firefox 46.0.1 for ubuntu.

Comment: I've detected some Maths bugs on Firefox with maps on  "translate" and "projection" operations

Comment: you could download the source and fix [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1066435)

Comment: Add your Update as "Answer" and mark it as correct, for future references to others users. You could add @RobertLongson answer if its correct

Comment: Yes, I will, but still need some workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, this is a known FireFox bug. Even if you did fix FireFox, it's going to take some time to propagate, and it'll never be backwards-fixed. So you still need a workaround.

One thing you can do — as long as the SVG's top-left is always at the 0,0 coordinate of its containing div (as is the case with your jsFiddle) — is replace the call to `d3.mouse(this)` with:

```
d3.mouse(this.parentNode)
```

That'll get the mouse coordinate from the parent of the SVG, which is a normal div, so apparently it's not affected by this bug and will get you the value you want on all platforms.

This does not address the root problem (for example `getClientBoundingRect` would still return the wrong values), but it works around your specific problem.

Comment: It will definitely solve the issue if we don't apply any transform over the svg element. Do you think is there another workaround that allow us transform to the svg element? would be nice not to be tied to that condition in the future.

Comment: @rahpuser you could apply svg transforms (via attributes) rather than css transforms

Comment: @RobertLongson the css transforms are applied by a third library, probably we are going to get rid of the library, so that should do the work.  Thanks